# PHP how to pass an array using POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have been all over stack overflow and read the various answers to similar questions but I'm still experiencing a problem so I'm definitely missing something.  My problem is simple:

I'm trying to pass an array from one page to another using POST.  I'm not getting the response I want as demonstrated below.  Any ideas?

Here is my form code:

```
$my_array = array("a", "b", "c", "d");

echo "<form action='post_to_this_page.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='book_ids[]' id='hiddenField' value=" $my_array " />";
echo "<input type='submit' name='formSubmit' value='Submit' />";
echo "</form>;
```

Here is "post_to_this_page.php:

```
$bookids = $_POST['book_ids'];
foreach($bookids as $thebookid)
{
     echo "Book Id : " . $thebookid . "<br />";
}
```

This is what prints out:

Book Id : Array

Obviously I'm trying to get a response like:

Book Id : a

Book Id : b

Book Id : c

Book Id : d

I'm sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong but I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks in advance for looking at my problem.  Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code is ok. First, obviously, it loops once because you only assign one position to `book_id` array. If you want more positions, you have to create more field inputs with `book_id[]` as name. And finally, you are echoing an array which is not correct because you will get a nice string saying `Array` and for that reason prints out `Array`.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to pass arrays in the POST, you must change your code a little bit.
You should iterate trough your '$my_array' and add multiple hidden input fields using the following code:

```
foreach ($my_array as $identifier) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='book_ids[]' value='$identifier' />";
}
```

Also, I removed the 'id' field from your input field, because there is not just 1 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try more like:

```
$bookids = $_POST['book_ids'];
foreach($bookids as $thebookid)
{
     echo "Book Id : " . print_r($thebookid, true) . "<br />";
}
```

`echo` cannot echo array, so you can use `print_r` to find out the value.

Comment: This doesn't really explain why his code loops only once.

Answer (score 0):

Either serialise your current value or have multiple inputs named `book_id[]` and listen for each `$_POST['book_id']`

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this

```
$my_array = array("a", "b", "c", "d");

echo "<form action='post_to_this_page.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='book_ids' id='hiddenField' value="implode('-', $my_array) " />";
echo "<input type='submit' name='formSubmit' value='Submit' />";
echo "</form>;
```

then turn it back to an array on the page you posted to.

```
$bookIds = explode('-',$_POST['book_ids']);
foreach($bookIds as $id)
    echo "Book Id: ".$id;
```

You're not actually passing an array, but the outcome is the same. just be sure your ids don't contain the character you're using for the delimiter('-' in y example.)

Comment: Thanks Bryan!  Implementing your suggestion worked like a charm!  Much appreciated.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using serialize:

```
<input name="my_var_name" value="<?php echo serialize($mi_array) ?>"
```

Then, in server side:

```
$my_var=unserialize($_POST['my_var_name']);
```

You can send string using post.